# Trouble booting Windows from USB

Tags: windows, boot, usb, installation

Not sure if there's a more appropriate SE site, but I've been having some real trouble today. My laptop stopped running Windows because I powered off holding the power button and I must've corrupted my hard drive.

My trouble is that I've downloaded and burned Windows 7 pro to USB. Initially I got as far as installing Windows on a partition, but when restarting, I ran into the same problem every time of Windows not being able to load because 'Hal is missing'. Startup repair was no help and I ended up going in circles. I next tried installing Windows 8.1 and all seemed to be going well until it said that Windows could not configure on my computer's hardware.

I've now tried installing Windows 7 Ultimate but after it boots from USB, the Windows logo comes up, followed by a black screen with a moveable cursor. It seems to be stuck there - I've left it for over half an hour with no change so I can't even attempt to install a new Windows. Any help at all appreciated, I've no idea what to try next. Many thanks.

Comment: Did you burn Windows into USB using [Windows USB/DVD Download Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool) ? Also please clarify, do you want to boot directly from USB, or boot from USB to install Windows on HDD?

Comment: @Jet yes, I tried with the Window's tool and with Isoburner to make sure. Ideally I'd just like to have a clean install, so I'd like to boot to install on HDD.

Comment: Do you have working Windows in computer? If yes, you can mount Windows 7 iso (using tools like [Daemon Tools](http://www.daemon-tools.cc/products/dtLite)) and run windows setup directly from PC. This way you can pass by errors caused by USB. Otherwise, try another USB stick. Is it still the same?

Comment: @jet How do you mean directly from PC? I have another laptop with a working Windows, but the laptop that's having issues won't boot at all. I don't think the USB is the problem either because I've tried 3 different versions of Windows 7 and the Windows 8 installation was fine until configuration problems. I've tried the USB on my work's computer too and it seemed fine. I don't have a second USB to try. Thanks for the help too :)

Comment: Can you get to Safe Mode now? If yes, it can help a lot. Also do you have any devices attached to laptop? Sometimes Windows won't boot when some USB devices are attached (like [this](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/computer-wont-boot-up-external-usb-hard-drive-attached-80463.html)) (I've seen such issues with USB mouse, keyboard). Unplug everything before booting (even USB mouse, and USB stick) and reboot

Comment: @Jet Can't reach safe mode, reload from last known settings or reach the Win 7 installation since installing Win 8. Before I tried installing Win 8, each time I tried safe mode, or any other option I got the 'HAL is missing' message. There's no other external devices attached. This seems a bit frustrating because it seems like a software issue but I can't erase and install new software!

Comment: @MikeMiller: Try using a Linux LiveCD/USB to wipe the HDD, then use Rufus to create a Win7 USB installer.

Comment: @Karan I've been trying this yesterday. Installed Ubuntu and everything seemed fine. Went to restart and the OP wouldn't load again, kept asking which OP I wanted to boot and then restarting. I've tried reinstalling but I seem to get a lot of i/o errors and on the previous attempt it said it couldn't finish installing possibly due to a faulty hard drive, so I guess that may be my problem.

Comment: Use any tool like Hiren's BootCD to diagnose HDD problems. Is it OK?

Comment: @Jet I'm pretty sure I fried my hard drive. Luckily I had a spare and all's okay now - I just learned my lesson not to power down by holding the power button and also that I should back up my work a lot more often! Thanks for taking the time.